# Tableau - Count customers with product pairs

Tags: tableau-api, aggregate-functions

Tableau question

How can I count unique number of customers who have product pairs.

I have a dataset with customer id and product.

**Sample dataset**

[image: 1]

I need to look like this! with count of customers in a product pair matrix

**Result View**

[image: 2]

Final goal is to create heatmap of product bundle popularity

Comment: What is meant by product pair? Customer 5 and 6 have one product each? Moreover, is it mandatory to have each customer two products? If no, how will you calculate relation from same product to itself?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok.  I think you need to reshape your data in tableau prep or in any other programming language.  What I have done is like that -
Add a new column in data like this -

[image: New column]

Thereafter use pivot_wider (rows to column) function in tableau prep (this functionality is not yet available in tableau desktop) on cols `Prod` and `Prod2` which will transform your data like this -

[image: transformed data]

Thereafter you can make a heatmap in tableau desktop like this

[image: heatmap]